# PageAsyncTask Update UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, pageasynctask

I am learning about asynchronous operations in ASP .NET. I found an article here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The code works, but I want to be able to update the UI during the long process. It only shows the result after the process has finished. I am using the same code for the AsyncClass as in the link mentioned. Here is the code:

```
            AsyncTask slowTask1 = new AsyncTask();
            PageAsyncTask task = new PageAsyncTask(slowTask1.OnBegin, slowTask1.OnEnd, slowTask1.OnTimeout, "Async1", true);
            Page.AsyncTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            Page.RegisterAsyncTask(task);
           // Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
            IAsyncResult result = slowTask1.OnBegin(this.Page,null,null,null);

            WaitHandle waitHandle = result.AsyncWaitHandle;
            waitHandle.WaitOne(2000, false);

            if(result.IsCompleted)
            {
                slowTask1.OnEnd(result);
                lbProgress.Text = slowTask1.GetAsyncTaskProgress();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            lbProgress.Text = slowTask1.GetAsyncTaskProgress();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it from code behind. While the response is sent to client that `request/response` is ended. So if you need to wait for the result of `Async` operation (somehow used in response) and still need to update page, use `AJAX` and pull data from client side.